# Need to create K8 env with driver name with credentioals

Tags: kubernetes, development-environment

I have to deploy one of the docker image using postsqlDB , connection srting is like below , what is best
methode i can use.

```
"postgresql://username@host.name.svc.cluster.local?sslmode=require"
```

I have used env like below but not working,

```
  -name : DB_ADDRESS
   value: "postgresql://username@tcp(host.name.svc.cluster.local)?sslmode=require"
```

Answer (score 0):

In past I had to create Postgresql DB. I would suggest you to use Helm chart [link](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql).
It gives you a lot of flexibility in configurations.

Comment: postgress is already up and running , need to add Postgresql details as a env in application deployment